# How to write join query using Kallax

Tags: go

I have this struct as a [go-kallax](https://github.com/src-d/go-kallax) model:

```
type Smsgateway struct {
    kallax.Model `table:"sms_gateway" pk:"id,autoincr"`
    ID         int64
    Status     int
    Branch     int   
    Name       string
    Created_at string 
    Created_by string
    Updated_at string
    Updated_by string
    Statusname *Status `fk:"ID"`
    /*Name1 string
    Statusname string
    Createdby string*/
}
```

where status store id of status table and my `Status` struct is

```
type Status struct {    
    kallax.Model `table:"status" pk:"id,autoincr"`
    ID         int64
    Active     int
    Updated_by int    
    Name       string
    Updated_at string
}
```

Now if I use go to generate the tables, I can only get Smsgateway table list but not the value of the `Name` field from status table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but ...

Assuming that the models lie in the module `persistence`

```
q := persistence.NewSmsGatewayQuery().WithStatus()
s := persistence.NewSmsGatewayStore(db)
smsGateway, _ := s.FindOne(q)
```

Now you can access the Name of the Status `smsGateway.Status.Name`.

**WithStatus()** tells kallax to also fetch the related model